# Abel–Plana formula with fractional offset

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series

The [Abel–Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) compares the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)$ to the integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f\left(n\right)-\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)dx=\frac{1}{2}f(0)+i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f\left(ix\right)-f\left(-ix\right)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\,dx.\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
In applications to the [Casimir force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) between two mirrors one is interested in the effect of different boundary conditions on the mirrors, producing a fractional offset $\nu\in(0,1)$ of the index $n$, so one wishes to compare $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n+\nu)$ to the same integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$.

The fractional offset $0<\nu<1$ can be accounted for by a phase shift in the Abel–Plana formula,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n+\nu)-\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=i\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{f(ix)}{e^{2\pi (x+ i\nu)}-1}-\frac{f(-ix)}{e^{2\pi (x- i\nu)}-1}\right)\,dx.\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}
Note that there is no $f(0)$ term on the r.h.s.

**Q:** I would like to be able to refer to \eqref{2}, is it in the literature? Alternatively, I would be happy to refer to an MO answer that derives it.

---

**Notes:**

Ramanujan gives several generalizations of the Abel-Plana formula \eqref{1}, including the case of a $\nu=1/2$ offset, and a formula that follows from \eqref{2} by subtracting the offsets $\nu=(1\pm\alpha)/2$, with $0<\alpha<1$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty[f(2n+1-\alpha)-f(2n+1+\alpha)]=\frac{\sin\pi\alpha}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{f(ix)+f(-ix)}{\cosh\pi x + \cos \pi\alpha}\,dx.\tag{3}\label{3}$$
<sub>See [Ramanujan and Koshliakov meet Abel and Plana](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.09819) by B.C. Berndt et al.</sub>

I could not find the formula \eqref{2} itself in [Ramanujan's notebook](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Ramanujan_s_Notebooks.html?id=Z__xZ9pNkZMC&redir_esc=y) (although I don't doubt that he knew it).

A more modern derivation for the case of a $\nu=1/2$ offset can be found in Appendix B.2 of Phys.Rev.Research **3**, 023201 (2021).

Comment: Might also be interesting to look at a fractional offset generalization of the Euler-Maclaurin formula, in the same sense as equation $(2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually did find a published derivation of the fractional-offset (2) of the Abel-Plana formula, in [A Generalized Mode Summation Formula of the Zero-Point Energy in a Cavity](https://doi.org/10.1143/JPSJ.72.1035) by Norio Inui (2003):

[image]

which is equivalent to (2).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Euler-Maclaurin-formula-revisited-Elliott/43a86582da7acc57944cee260d1654bfbc5f251c

A while ago I was looking at using similar formulas for numerical integration and analysis. Here is a reference, I'm not sure how relevant it is. I might add some related ones if I find some.

Comment: thanks, but no Abel-Plana in this reference, I'm afraid.